# requestLocationUpdates minTime parameter purpose

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I'm creating an application (For educational purposes) which records the user's location every 30 minutes, and enables the user the view all the locations on the map. I don't want updates to be more frequent than 30 minutes, but they are.

This is how I call `requestLocationUpdates`:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  30 * 60 * 1000,  0, pe);
```

Now, the documentation clearly says:

> The elapsed time between location updates will never be less than minTime

But I did see some answers here on SO stating differently ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4536911/797390), for example).

It seems like I'm getting updates whenever they are available from the GPS. The GPS icon never turns off and the updates rate becomes greater than 1 update/second. So I have 2 questions here:

1. The `minTime` parameter doesn't fulfill its purpose, not even as a hint (Yea, a hint to 30 minutes update rate leads to more than update a second...). What does it do, then?
2. Is there any other way to do it? I don't want the GPS to be enabled all the time because it will consume my battery too fast. Maybe I could schedule alarms repeating each 30 minutes, and call `requestSingleUpdate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The minTime parameter doesn't fulfill its purpose, not even as a hint (Yea, a hint to 30 minutes update rate leads to more than update a second...). What does it do, then?

From Jellybean onwards devices must observe the `minTime` parameter, so it does have a purpose (now).

> Is there any other way to do it? I don't want the GPS to be enabled all the time because it will consume my battery too fast. Maybe I could schedule alarms repeating each 30 minutes, and call requestSingleUpdate?

Yes, use a Handler to request one update with `requestSingleUpdate()` every 30 minutes.

I've tackled this before in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13093613/1267661), let me know if the code in that answer helps and if you have any questions it doesn't address.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look there. I don't think a Handler is an option because my application may be dead between updates, but using the `AlarmManager` is similar. My device runs 2.3.3, But interesting, I would never guess your answer to the first question.

Comment: In that case, an AlarmManager is the way to go. You can also use a background Service to fetch and save the new location if you don't want to bother the user.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter, min distance difference in meters is set to zero, it causes constant updates. 
Prefer using requestSingleUpdate within a timer+handler on a desired period in minutes.