# Get the real interval scan of an android application

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I've a problem to understand if the Android do a wifi scan when my application run the startScan() command or the kernel manages the wifi interval with another timing.

I read this conversation:
[Is there a way to explicitly control WiFi scan intervals in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885767/is-there-a-way-to-explicitly-control-wifi-scan-intervals-in-android)

It seems there isn't a way to tell to the system to scan on a set interval.
So, Does way exist to impose a scan interval and tell to the system to do scansions with this interval for my application)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is not possible because is a task handle by the system. See [this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2108553) in XDA. Seems that there is a way but is need to modify the file build.prop.

Comment: Thank you. I take a look and it seems a good way to solve the problem (for GingerBread version and lower). Moreover searching about your proposal I find in this [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37621/where-can-i-find-settings-for-wifi-internal-scan-period) another method to understand and manage the interval of scansion.